# Create column from a substring of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe object. I want to create new columns from substrings of an existing column. My data looks like this:

```
    Date        variable                 want1          want2   want3
0   02-01-08    Australia - Sydney - A   Australia      Sydney  A
1   03-01-08    Australia - Sydney - A   Australia      Sydney  A
2   04-01-08    Australia - Sydney - A   Australia      Sydney  A
3   05-01-08    Canada - Toronto - B     Canada         Toronto B
4   06-01-08    Canada - Toronto - B     Canada         Toronto B
```

where `want1` to `want3` are what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.str.split` for this:

```
df[['want1', 'want2', 'want3']] = df['variable'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I only want the first 2 columns?

Answer (score 1):

### `pd.Series.extract`

```
pat = '(?P<want1>.*) - (?P<want2>.*) - (?P<want3>.*)'
df.join(df.variable.str.extract(pat, expand=True))

       Date                variable      want1    want2 want3
0  02-01-08  Australia - Sydney - A  Australia   Sydney     A
1  03-01-08  Australia - Sydney - A  Australia   Sydney     A
2  04-01-08  Australia - Sydney - A  Australia   Sydney     A
3  05-01-08    Canada - Toronto - B     Canada  Toronto     B
4  06-01-08    Canada - Toronto - B     Canada  Toronto     B
```